# Lombok with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> 
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>  
    <version>1.16.6</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add the above lines in `pom.xml` ref https://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/index.html

What these lines will do?

Will they download and install Lombok in my project?

If yes, this is not working.

@Data anotation not creating getter setters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use Lombok by simply putting it as a dependency, you must install it to your favorite IDE, too. See the [documentation here](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html):

> Project Lombok is available as a single jar file on the project site.
>   It includes the APIs for development as an installer for IDE
>   integration. On most systems, simply double-clicking the jar file will
>   launch the installer. If the system is not configured to correctly
>   launch jar files, it can also be run from the command line as follows:
>
> java -jar lombok.jar

The dependencies are additionally to that, not instead.

Comment: Thank you Florian. Is there any other alternative which i dont need to install in ide and can work on project basis

Comment: I have never used lombok in a real project, just played around with it and found it to be to "hacky" to be of any use for me, so I really can't help you there, sorry. I doubt it, anyway.

Comment: You can have a look at http://immutables.github.io/ if you only need property support. Since it uses code generation i.o. bytecode manipulation no plugins in IDE's are required.